# UWP BarcodeScanner does not recognize Code39 Barcode

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, windows-10-universal, barcode-scanner

I'm currently developing an UWP App in which one step is to scan a barcode encoded in code39 using the camera.

With other (UWP-)Apps I found in the store my sample code does get recognized correctly as code39 encoded (so I assume it is a valid code).

I looked at the BarcodeScanner Sample from the [microsoft uwp samples on github](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BarcodeScanner)
(I also looked at the CameraBarcodeScanner sample, which got removed from the github recently)

When I use `BarcodeScanner` and `ClaimedBarcodeScanner` classes from `Windows.Devices.PointOfService`, other barcodes (EAN8 or EAN13) get recognized correctly. (So I assume barcode regognition as such works)

I tried using `SetActiveSymbologiesAsync` to enable the scanner to find code39 barcodes. Whenever I call it without `BarcodeSymbologies.Ean8` in the list, an exception gets thrown:

```
"A device attached to the system is not functioning. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007001F)"
```

When I call it with `BarcodeSymbologies.Ean8` in the list, it falsely recognizes an EAN8 code when pointing the camera to the code39 barcode.

Here is my code:

```
private void OnScannerDataReceived(ClaimedBarcodeScanner sender, BarcodeScannerDataReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    var dataLabel = string.Format("{0}", Encoding.UTF8.GetString(args.Report.ScanData));
    var symbol = BarcodeSymbologies.GetName(args.Report.ScanDataType);
    Debug.WriteLine($"LABEL: {dataLabel} | BARCODE: {symbol}.");
    BarcodeReceived?.Invoke(this, dataLabel);
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide your hardware information? We need some details for reference.

Comment: I've tried it on the following devices:


* Sony Vaio VPCSB2 (internal webcam)

* Dell XPS15 (internal webcam)

* Panasonic FZ-G1 (internal webcam)

* all of the above with an Microsoft HD3000 USB-Webcam

As no configuration could detect my code39 barcode, I assume the problem to be software related.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for reporting this issue.

Well, the scenario you asked is using our in-box software decoder with a standard camera lens. Unfortunately we have discovered issues with this decoder accurately reading 1D barcodes, including Code 39 and will be addressing this in a future release.

Code 39 works fine with **physical** barcode scanners, so this is an issue specific to the **camera lens decoder**. We hope to have a new software decoder available in a future release that will address this issue. We would recommend using this camera lens decoder with QR Code only for now.

Comment: I understand that. What I don't understand is, that Code39 worked in past releases without problems. I have the same setup and at some point in the last 3 or 4 weeks there seemed to be a change. Interestingly the Barcode samples from the UWP GitHub project removed too. What has been changed?

Answer (score 0):

@Nasto,

The Spring 2018 update to Windows 10 version 1803 has introduced a new software decoder that will support Code39.  You can find more information at https://aka.ms/camerabarcode.  The UWP sample application for barcode scanner has also been updated to demonstrate camera barcode support.

Terry Warwick, Microsoft

Comment: I look forward to being able to use this but since it only supports 1803 and higher, those of us with OEM devices (such as my Honeywell CT50) will have to wait for this because the OEM has us stuck on an older version of Win10. Also, you seem very knowledgable on the barcode scanning, UWP and Honeywell, please check this post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/SharePoint/en-US/d4b87b0f-fa09-40a9-8acb-d25cae840ab7/getting-quota-device-attached-to-the-system-is-not-functioningquot-when-trying-to-enable-barcode?forum=wpdevelop